# how to count the number of rectangles on an image using Aforge

Tags: c#, blob, aforge

I am using aforge dll to detect rectangles on an image.
Example:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = "rectangles.png";
    Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);

    // locating objects
    BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();

    blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
    blobCounter.MinHeight = 400;
    blobCounter.MinWidth = 600;

    blobCounter.ProcessImage(image);
    Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();

    // check for rectangles
    SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();

    foreach (var blob in blobs)
    {

        List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blob);
        List<IntPoint> cornerPoints;

        // use the shape checker to extract the corner points
        if (shapeChecker.IsQuadrilateral(edgePoints, out cornerPoints))
        {
            // only do things if the corners form a rectangle
            if (shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(cornerPoints) == PolygonSubType.Rectangle)
            {
                How do i count how many rectangles there is in here
                //List<Point> Points = new List<Point>();

                //foreach (var point in cornerPoints)
                //{

                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in the above I want to count and return how many rectangle there are in an image. [image]

So my output should be `count = 3` because there are 3 rectangles. How do I count them?

Comment: `var count = 0; if(isRectangle) count++; Console.WriteLine(count );`

Comment: this does not work, it doesnt detect 3 rectangles

Comment: What do the lines `blobCounter.MinHeight = 400; blobCounter.MinWidth = 600;` do?

Comment: @MarkusDeibel i was giving it the height and width of the entire image

Comment: I think your interpretation of MinHeight and MinWidth might be wrong. According to [the docs](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/5fd9bd3a-a7cd-a7e8-0947-bf8a15ceee4e.htm) _The property specifies minimum object's height acceptable by blob counting routine_ [...]. The way I'm reading this your image (and its contents) will not be counted because neither meets the min height and width (image is 488x111) you provided. What happens if you reduce the values to 10 and 10?